# Matching false (== undefined, null) in ClojureScript core.match

Tags: javascript, clojure, pattern-matching, clojurescript, core.match

I'm trying to match a `false` value of map's key, which in javascript effectively means also `undefined`, `null` etc... It seems to me that core.match matches the value exactly. Is there any way to do this?

The other way would be to match "not `true`", but the docs don't give me any hint how to do this either.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `:or` patterns:

```
(match [x]
  [(:or false nil)] true
  [_] false)
```

returns `true` if `x` is `false` or `nil`, `false` otherwise.

Alternatively, you could use `:guard` patterns:

```
(match [x]
  [(_ :when not)] true
  [_] false)
```

`:when` patterns would also work (with `(defpred not)`), but they can be tricky to get right and bring no benefit over guards in this case.